# Allow customer to select an available time based on the date they select

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch-api, appointment

I am having trouble with my javascript & an API where the API GETS appointments based on the date selected. Ideally the customer picks a time, then a bunch of buttons pop up when they select that time, when a time is selected the rest of the form is displayed (not shown below, in a different JS file this one is a dummy project until i figure it out and add it to the original JS file"

```
 `<button id="T08:00" class="timeButton">8:00am</button>`
```

Just imagine about 18 of these from 8:30-5:00. I chose to put the ISO format as the ID hoping that would help.
I wrote some JS that console.logs the date selected in ISO format, hoping i can use that date to fetch appointments which i was able to do.

```
function convertDateToISO() {
  const datePicker = document.getElementById('date-picker');
  const selectedDate = new Date(datePicker.value);
  const isoDate = selectedDate.toISOString();
  console.log(isoDate);

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json',
      authorization: 'Bearer '
    }
  };

  fetch(`https://api.shopmonkey.io/v2/appointments?limit=19&offset=0&sort=startDate&from=${isoDate}`, options)

    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}


const datePicker = document.getElementById('date-picker');
datePicker.addEventListener('change', convertDateToISO);



function showTimes() {
  const datePicker = document.getElementById('date-picker');
  const timesContainer = document.getElementById('times-container');
  const hasDateChanged = datePicker.value !== '';
  
  if (hasDateChanged) {
    timesContainer.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    console.error('Please select a date before continuing.');
  }
}

const continueBtn = document.getElementById('continueBtn');
continueBtn.addEventListener('click', showTimes);
function hideOtherTimes(event) {
  const clickedButton = event.target;
  const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.timeButton');
  
  allButtons.forEach(button => {
    if (button !== clickedButton) {
      button.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
  console.log(clickedButton.id);
}

const timeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.timeButton');
timeButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', hideOtherTimes);
});
```

I tried to loop through the array of appointments from the JSON response and log the startDates objects to the console if the date had the same day,time & year as the isoDate. I tried to at least get the similar dates to log to the console so if a date of 4/20 was selected & there were three appointments for that day we would only console log three appointments

```
fetch(`https://api.shopmonkey.io/v2/appointments?limit=19&offset=0&sort=startDate&from=${isoDate}`, options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    const appointments = response.data;
    const isoYear = new Date(isoDate).getFullYear();
    const isoMonth = new Date(isoDate).getMonth();
    const isoDay = new Date(isoDate).getDate();
    const isoHour = new Date(isoDate).getHours();
    const isoMinute = new Date(isoDate).getMinutes();
    
    for (let i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++) {
      const startDate = new Date(appointments[i].startDate);
      const startYear = startDate.getFullYear();
      const startMonth = startDate.getMonth();
      const startDay = startDate.getDate();
      const startHour = startDate.getHours();
      const startMinute = startDate.getMinutes();
      
      if (isoYear === startYear && isoMonth === startMonth && isoDay === startDay && isoHour === startHour && isoMinute === startMinute) {
        console.log(startDate);
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

led to this error T.js:40 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at GET.js:26:40

Comment: Could you confirm whether your second code snippet is `GET.js`? It is the only code that attempts to access a `length` property (as mentioned in your error. If so, it would suggest that you are trying to access `data` from the JSON response of the API but there is no `data` property.

Comment: Both snippets are GET.js @Wongjn